# Limiting WiFi bandwitdh to users connecting to Access Point

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, bandwidth, wireless-access-point, limited-access

I have setup my Laptop to be a Access point so others nearby can connect to it. Now, I would like to limit the speed to those users so they cannot overload the Internet connection with their requests.

How would I go about doing this in Windows XP.

***Edit: I am following the instructions as described in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADpHIeBSFUk) video.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you use NAT for sharing your Internet access or your computer works as a proxy?

In the first case you might want to try [the following tool](http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html).

In the second case there are plenty of Proxy Servers that are free and support traffic shaping. Once I used the [CCProxy](http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/) on my computer with similar purposes.

Comment: I "think" I am using proxy. Basically I am doing what I described on a different post, to which you have replied already ;). Does that one count as proxy?